# Importing data from a text file

Tags: vb.net

Ok, so I'm doing a total overhaul. Thanks to you I got the months working properly! But as you said, I should be modifying this to try to understand better. So I tried to add 2 more list boxes with something to test. The program is now testing milestones (years old - 10 years old through 100). I edited the code but I don't know what line to check to change from testing the month to the year? So the new list box I added displays the same information as the month test, versus what I'm trying to accomplish. So for example: John Doe 4/9/2003 would show up in the '10' milestone.

```
  Private Sub lbMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lbMonth.SelectedIndexChanged
    If lbMonth.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Return
    lbPerson.Items.Clear()
    Dim index As Integer = lbMonth.SelectedIndex
    For Each ele In Birthdays(index + 1)
        lbPerson.Items.Add(ele)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub lbMilestone_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lbMilestone.SelectedIndexChanged
    If lbMilestone.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Return
    lbPerson2.Items.Clear()
    Dim index As Integer = lbMilestone.SelectedIndex
    For Each ele2 In Birthdays2(index)
        lbPerson2.Items.Add(ele2)
    Next
End Sub

Private Birthdays(12) As List(Of String)
Private Birthdays2(10) As List(Of String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'initialize the Month list
    lbMonth.Items.Clear()
    lbMonth.Items.Add("January")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("February")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("March")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("April")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("May")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("June")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("July")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("August")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("September")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("October")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("November")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("December")

    lbMilestone.Items.Clear()
    lbMilestone.Items.Add("10")
    lbMilestone.Items.Add("20")
    lbMilestone.Items.Add("30")
    lbMilestone.Items.Add("40")
    lbMilestone.Items.Add("50")
    lbMilestone.Items.Add("60")
    lbMilestone.Items.Add("70")
    lbMilestone.Items.Add("80")
    lbMilestone.Items.Add("90")
    lbMilestone.Items.Add("100")
    'initialize the Lists (Instance required in order to access each list-object)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 12
        Birthdays(i) = New List(Of String)
    Next

    For j As Integer = 0 To 10
        Birthdays2(j) = New List(Of String)
    Next

    'load some birthdays
    Dim filename As String = Application.StartupPath + "\Birthday.txt"
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filename) Then Throw New Exception("Filename """ + filename + """ does not exist!")

    Dim fileContent As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filename)
    Dim lines() As String = Split(fileContent, vbCrLf)
    For Each ele As String In lines
        Dim line As String = ele.Trim
        Dim datePos As Integer = line.LastIndexOf(vbTab) 'find last space between name and date
        If datePos < 5 Then Continue For 'if full name is less than 5 chars, then it probably not a line with an entry
        Dim dateString As String = Mid(line, datePos + 2) 'all after that last space is date
        Dim name As String = Mid(line, 1, datePos).Trim ' all before that last space is name
        'Dim birthday As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(parts(1).Trim) ' used this conversion before, but lets try the other way
        Dim birthday As Date
        Try
            birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Continue For
        End Try

        Dim month As Integer = birthday.Month
        Dim year As Integer = CInt(Date.Now.Subtract(birthday).TotalDays / 365 / 10)
        Birthdays(month).Add(name)
        Birthdays2(year).Add(name)
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Okay, lets see.. please rename the Birthday2 to an appropriate name, maybe something with deci and years or so. Also the original may be renamed, but i think thats okay so far. 2. instead of adding a complete block, you just need to add 1-2 lines: like the line **Dim month as Integer...** you will add your definition **Dim year...** right below the month definition.But change the right side: **= CInt(Date.Now.Subtract(birthday).TotalYears / 10)** and then also add the comand to add it to the second list by year, as you already wrote. Then change the new for each to iterate through Birthday2 :)

Comment: explanation: after you 'parsed' the birthday correctly, there you can extract any information, even 5 different ones, and fill the data to 5 different locations. That is more useful than reading the entire file 5 times (and 5 times parsing). **#** The for-each 'iterates' through a collection, so whatever you have in it, the following code lines will be executed for every single item in that collection. **#** Since there is an array of collections, we use a number to access one specific collection. To show an item in a list, just add it to list.Items.Add(your_item)

Comment: @Amegon Well, I have been playing with this code and not getting anywhere to be honest. I'm getting an error, TotalYears is not a member of System.Timespan. I tried changing it to TotalDays / 365.. no luck. I posted my edited code. Right now the list boxes still display the same information. Frustrating!!

Comment: @Cliff, why would you replace your question with "EDITED"? This removes any possible benefit that someone else could find the question and answer and get some help from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project and add 2 listboxes. Name one listbox **lbMonth**, the other **lbPerson**

then insert the following code:

```
Private Sub lbMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbMonth.SelectedIndexChanged
    If lbMonth.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Return
    lbPerson.Items.Clear()
    Dim index As Integer = lbMonth.SelectedIndex
    For Each ele In Birthdays(index + 1)
        lbPerson.Items.Add(ele)
    Next
End Sub

Private Birthdays(12) As List(Of String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'initialize the Month list
    lbMonth.Items.Clear()
    lbMonth.Items.Add("January")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("February")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("March")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("April")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("May")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("June")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("July")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("August")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("September")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("October")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("November")
    lbMonth.Items.Add("December")

    'initialize the Lists (Instance required in order to access each list-object)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 12
        Birthdays(i) = New List(Of String)
    Next

    'load some birthdays
    Dim filename As String = Application.StartupPath + "\names.txt"
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filename) Then Throw New Exception("Filename """ + filename + """ does not exist!")

    Dim fileContent As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filename)
    Dim lines() As String = Split(fileContent, vbCrLf)
    For Each ele As String In lines
        Dim line As String = ele.Trim
        Dim datePos As Integer = line.LastIndexOf(" ") 'find last space between name and date
        If datePos < 5 Then Continue For 'if full name is less than 5 chars, then it probably not a line with an entry
        Dim dateString As String = Mid(line, datePos + 2) 'all after that last space is date
        Dim name As String = Mid(line, 1, datePos).Trim ' all before that last space is name
        'Dim birthday As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(parts(1).Trim) ' used this conversion before, but lets try the other way
        Dim birthday As Date
        Try
            birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Continue For
        End Try
        Dim month As Integer = birthday.Month
        Birthdays(month).Add(name)
    Next

End Sub
```

You need to rename the birthday filename to "names.txt" and probably place it to project/bin/Debug or anywhere else where you run the program executable.

The exception should help you to find the correct path.

**Update**

and make sure both listboxes are relative large (can show all 12 months).

Test the program. You should see something happen when you select month 7 or 8 (if you use the 3 entries that you listed)

**Update2**

I have modified the code by adding a Try..Catch block to fix exceptions, if the file contains empty lines/lines with invalid data in them.

just replace the code in your project.

Also please make sure it is " " space, not a tab, that is used in the text file. if tabs are used, then replace

```
Dim datePos As Integer = line.LastIndexOf(" ")
```

with

```
Dim datePos As Integer = line.LastIndexOf(vbTab)
```

good luck this time :) If it still fails, then we can make the string to ate conversion to a function and test it a bit more, or even do it more manually by getting all 3 numbers, and then creating a new date with day, month, and year (each as integer)

**Update3**

Changed Birthday array to have 13 fields (0 to 12, 0 not used anymore)

Changed to initialize also all 13 fields

Changed to read from index+1, since January is index 0, February index 1 etc.

Comment: Thank you for the work, but I'm getting an error on this line: Dim birthday As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: hmm maybe with the line **Dim birthday As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString)** instead? Can you use the immediate window, and enter the following: _?New Date.ToString("M/d/yyyy")_  and post your result here? It is mainly an issue with language and date formatting setting (well, I seem to be too adobe to do it correctly, culture setting independent). After solving this, you should have a running program

Comment: with the new dim birthday line I'm now getting the error "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0." I don't even know what an immediate window is though! Ha..

Comment: Edited the answer, please try again

Comment: Thanks! I got it working, there is only 1 holdup though. For some reason all of the months show up 1 month later than it actually is? So for example Barack Obama 8/4/1961 shows in September, etc. I'm sorry for taking up so much of your time!

Comment: OH, I just checked, so.. lets do a quick and dirty fix.. updating answer

Comment: So now it should work. I recommend to set some breakpoints and then run it. If code stops, move the mouse over some objects to see their content. You will only improve if you try to understand every command, and even better if you try to modify some lines and check the results. Main work was mainly the parsing (text to objects) here. If you like, then you can add your initial code with openFileDialog, offering to load additional text files. Just make sure to not create new birthday lists if you want to add more birthdays instead of replacing the first ones.

Comment: I am taking your advice and trying better to understand the commands. I have modified my program to understand better. I edited my entire first post. Do you have any insight? Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see your reply. I will see what I can do tonight! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I know it is not easy to find a good start with programming. According to the stuff we used here, I would strongly recommend to follow a tutorial for programming with vb.net. Many basic examples will help you **a lot** to understand much more. Not sure about a good start in english, so here is a german tutorial, translated with google: http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fopenbook.galileocomputing.de%2Fvb_net%2F  If you find another one originally in english, then perfect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27951/discussion-between-amegon-and-cliff)

Answer (score 0):

So lets change the following (and btw. nice idea to use days/365):

```
    Dim month As Integer = birthday.Month
    Dim year As Integer = CInt(Date.Now.Subtract(birthday).TotalDays / 365)
    Birthdays(month).Add(name)
```

you want to have 10 year steps, so divide the years by 10

```
    Dim month As Integer = birthday.Month
    Dim year As Integer = CInt(Date.Now.Subtract(birthday).TotalDays / 365 / 10)
    Birthdays(month).Add(name)
```

and also you need to use that calculated year information for something.. lets fill the other field :)

```
    Dim month As Integer = birthday.Month
    Dim year As Integer = CInt(Date.Now.Subtract(birthday).TotalDays / 365 / 10)
    Birthdays(month).Add(name)
    Birthdays2(year).Add(name)
```

Now checking the other part..

```
Private Sub lbMilestone_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lbMilestone.SelectedIndexChanged
    If lbMilestone.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Return
    lbPerson2.Items.Clear()
    Dim index As Integer = lbMilestone.SelectedIndex
    For Each ele2 In Birthdays(index + 1)
        lbPerson2.Items.Add(ele2)
    Next
End Sub
```

Most of it is correct, but you read from the 'old' month list

```
    For Each ele2 In Birthdays(index + 1)
```

so change the line to

```
    For Each ele2 In Birthdays2(index + 1)
```

and also I think 10 should represent age 0-9 years, so if the first element (index=0) is clicked, then the persons from Birthdays2(0) should be returned. (= remove the **+ 1** )

```
    For Each ele2 In Birthdays(index)
```

so the method should look like the following:

```
Private Sub lbMilestone_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lbMilestone.SelectedIndexChanged
    If lbMilestone.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Return
    lbPerson2.Items.Clear()
    Dim index As Integer = lbMilestone.SelectedIndex
    For Each ele2 In Birthdays(index)
        lbPerson2.Items.Add(ele2)
    Next
End Sub
```

**Update**

Change the method to use another sub:

```
       [...]
        Dim dateString As String = Mid(line, datePos + 2) 'all after that last space is date
        Dim name As String = Mid(line, 1, datePos).Trim ' all before that last space is name
        'Dim birthday As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(parts(1).Trim) ' used this conversion before, but lets try the other way
        AddUser(name, dateString)
    Next

End Sub
```

and here the sub: (you see that it is almost 1:1, except for the **Exit sub** since no for-loop is there to exit, but since the method contains all the code executed until end of the loop, therefore an **exit sub** here does the same as an **continue for** in previous version.

```
Private Sub AddUser(Name As String, dateString As String)
    Dim birthday As Date
    Try
        birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim month As Integer = birthday.Month
    Birthdays(month).Add(Name)

    Dim year As Integer = CInt(Date.Now.Subtract(birthday).TotalDays / 356 / 10)
    Birthdays2(year).Add(Name)
End Sub
```

now when the user enters new data, you just need to call the method

```
AddUser("new name", "1/2/1934")
```

or with variables

```
AddUser(tbYour_name_textbox, tbYour_birthday_date_textbox)
```

Comment: Thanks again. It really helps when you break things down. I edited my code again.. ha! But For some reason due to the rounding every person is in one milestone too high (so people that should be listed in '10' are displayed in '20' and so on). Dang I'm so close to nailing it! Someone who is 21 should show in the '30' milestone, instead of the '20' as 30 is the next milestone. Also I am in search online of a refresh button, so when the user enters a new name the program will be able to restart so to speak to show the new name in the listbox. I'll let you know how I make out.

Comment: I updated my answer to change code for this. Since you never want to write code lines that do exactly the same, we put the part (that adds a name to a list) to another sub. That way we can call it at the place where the code originally was, and also call the code at the new place, too (which is the part where the user clicks on add, after entering name and birthday) If the user cna select a birthday and it is already a date (instead of a string), then move the datestring conversion back to the sub_load part, and change the calling parameters for adduser to accept a date instead of datestring